# Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts

Tags: javascript

I'd like to add support for keyboard shortcuts to a couple of pages in my web application by intercepting the keypress event handler of the document object, not the accesskey attribute.

The problem is that every browser has its own keyboard combinations, so it's impossible to come up with a set of keyboard combinations that work on all web browsers and yet consistent.(e.g. It'd be silly if the shortcut for save was <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> while one for delete was <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd>.)

So I figured it would be just simpler to override browser shortcuts altogether in a couple of pages with mine.

All downside aside, is it possible? If so, how do you do it?

Comment: On a personal note, please avoid overriding common browser shortcuts that are consistent between browsers such as `C-w`, `C-t`, `C-S-t`...  Some of Google's products override common browser shortcuts and its incredibly annoying!

Comment: It can be difficult to know what are "common" user shortcuts. For example, do many users use `C-e` or is it relatively fine to override? It'd be great to have a chart of percents of users who use each browser shortcut.

Comment: @JKillian Indeed, but where do you measure the cutoff? The 1% or 0.5% are still going to be annoyed.  I'm sure engineers at Google are aware they are block shortcuts but trying to find shortcuts that are useful to a wider audience.  (Then there's the question, are they useful to the wider audience?) But none of these are questions appropriate to stack overflow!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

There's an excellent coverage of this here: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

As for whether this is something that should be done, stackoverflow's question editor override's quite a few keys without disrupting too much (hover over the toolbar buttons).

Comment: You need to handle *keydown* event with `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation();`. While handling keydown one thing to remember is  that it can occur multiple times if user keeps key pressed for bit longer.

Comment: You should answer the question directly on Stack Overflow, not link somewhere else (external links can break or change or not directly answer the question). See [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really “good answers”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Comment: I really hate the way Ctrl-L gets stolen when I'm using StackOverflow's question editor, though. Makes it harder to do web searches while editing questions.

Answer (score 47):

```
onkeydown = function(e){
  if(e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 'S'.charCodeAt(0)){
    e.preventDefault();
    //your saving code
  }
}
```

Comment: In a lot of situations, I don't think that would work.  With keys like 'tab', a lot of browsers will intercept the command before the script can alter the key's behavior correctly.

Comment: `event.preventDefault` only works (when it does) on W3C compliant browsers, not (say) the dominant browser on the general web, Microsoft's -- unless, of course, you're using a library like jQuery that adds it in for you.

Comment: T.J.> You mean jQuery can override keyboard shortcuts even on IE?

Answer (score 15):

Here is my solution to this problem:

Most (if not all) of the browser's shortcuts will be overriden. Only system ones, like <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> or the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key won't.

```
document.onkeydown = overrideKeyboardEvent;
document.onkeyup = overrideKeyboardEvent;
var keyIsDown = {};

function overrideKeyboardEvent(e){
  switch(e.type){
    case "keydown":
      if(!keyIsDown[e.keyCode]){
        keyIsDown[e.keyCode] = true;
        // do key down stuff here
      }
    break;
    case "keyup":
      delete(keyIsDown[e.keyCode]);
      // do key up stuff here
    break;
  }
  disabledEventPropagation(e);
  e.preventDefault();
  return false;
}
function disabledEventPropagation(e){
  if(e){
    if(e.stopPropagation){
      e.stopPropagation();
    } else if(window.event){
      window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This isn't stopping ALT+E from bringing up browser Edit menu.

Comment: can we override "ctrl + u", "f12". If we can't override, I was thinking when at least key will be pressed, I will internally trigger the event again. Then, if it's opened, it will be closed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my Solution:

```
document.onkeydown = function () {
                       if ((window.event.keyCode == 121) && (window.event.ctrlKey))) {
               window.event.returnValue = false;
               window.event.cancelBubble = true;
               window.event.keyCode = 0;
               return false;
           }
       }
```

Comment: This will simply change the event key code and no action will be performed by the selected default key