# Shortcut on Silverlight , and default browser shortcuts

Tags: javascript, asp.net, performance, silverlight-4.0

I want to handle shortcut in my app  so I keydown event handler as following

```
Application.Current.RootVisual.AddHandler(UIElement.KeyDownEvent, new KeyEventHandler(HandleKeyDown), true);
```

The problem is with the shortcuts like Ctrl+S , Ctrl+T , those fire the browser shortcuts

I tried to disable it from the aspx that hold the silverlight using javescript as following

```
onkeydown = function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 's'.charCodeAt(0)) {
        e.preventDefault();


    }
};
```

any idea how to disable the default browser shortcuts ,and use mine

Comment: check this question, I think it could help
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

okey. try this jquery plugin

https://github.com/jeresig/jquery.hotkeys

but read this first

> Firefox is the most liberal one in the manner of letting you capture all short-cuts even >those that are built-in in the browser such as Ctrl-t for new tab, or Ctrl-a for selecting >all text. You can always bubble them up to the browser by returning true in your handler.
>
> Others, (IE) either let you handle built-in short-cuts, but will add their functionality >after your code has executed. Or (Opera/Safari) will not pass those events to the DOM at all.
>
> So, if you bind Ctrl-Q or Alt-F4 and your Safari/Opera window is closed don't be surprised.

It worked fine with me on Chrome but in FF both the JS event as well as the browser event were executed.