# How to remove shortcuts in tinymce?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to remove the `ctrl+s` shortcut that saves the contents of the editor. Is there a way to remove this shortcut in particular. I was trying to look at the [TinyMCE documentation](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/api/tinymce/tinymce.shortcuts/), but I didn't understand where they got editor from. How do I implement the remove shortcut function in the tinymce.init function or anywhere so that when the user does `ctrl+s` it doesn't save the editor and nothing happens. I've tried to look for solutions online, but I couldn't find one for this case.

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19791696/overriding-shortcut-assignments-in-tinymce

Comment: @zinc this isn't working for me, when I add 83 as the key code, it still manages to refresh the page