# How to keep the OS "Save As" dialog from poppng up when Ctrl S is entered

Tags: javascript

I have some JavaScript that gets triggered by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> and saves a local structure, call "group" below. But despite the last three lines of the code, the OS (Windows 7) "Save As" dialog pops up. Is there any way to keep the OS from popping up its Save As dialog?

Thanks

```
 $(document).on('keydown',function(e) { 
    if ( e.ctrlKey && e.keyCode == 83 ) {  // CTRL+S - save group
        var raw_groupName = prompt("Group Name: ", g.last_groupName); 
        var groupName = raw_groupName.replace(/ /g,"_");

        saveGroup(groupName);

        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault();
        return (false);
    };
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 1):

I listened for the `keydown` event and attached the listener to the `window` object.

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function (evt) {
    if (evt.ctrlKey && evt.keyCode === 83) {
        evt.preventDefault();
    }
}, false);
```

Above code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/s66JK/

Comment: Ah!  The problem is the prompt call. Adding that breaks your jsfiddle (updated to http://jsfiddle.net/s66JK/7/ )  and lets the "Save As" dialog come up. So why in the world does that happen?! - Thanks

Comment: What browser are you running? I'm on Windows 7 and your fiddle still works for me. Also make sure in the fiddle that you have focus in the output frame as that's where it would be in the real app. If you move focus to other parts of the window it won't work since `window` here is the output iframe.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably listening to the `onkeypress` event which will always give you an `e.keyCode` equal to 0. Have you tried putting a breakpoint inside your `if` ? It's most likely always false. `onkeypress` uses `e.charCode`.

I tried your code and it works with the `onkeydown` event.