# How to handle ctrl+tab key in extjs 3.4?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs3

I am working on Extjs3.4. I want to keymap ctrl+tab in my application. but when I try to use it, it opens my next browser tab. How can  I solve it?

This is my code :-

```
var keyMap = new Ext.KeyMap(Ext.getDoc(), {
            key: Ext.EventObject.TAB,//9
            ctrl: true,
            stopEvent : true,
            fn: function () { console.log('it works'); },
            scope: this
        });
```

Please give some suggestion.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Comment: I tried with it. But still problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put a listener in the respective field (text or whatever)

```
                listeners: {
                    keydown:    {     //tab could be listened in keydown
                        element: 'el',
                        fn: function(e){ 
                            if(e.urKey && e.urAnotherKey)
                                alert('keydown, execute my action');
                        }
                    },                
                    keypress:    {
                        element: 'el',
                        fn: function(){ 
                            alert('keypress');
                        }
                    }
                }
```