# How can I prevent IE10 from triggering print when using shortkeys?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have implemented a bunch of shortkeys on my page but in order for them all to work i have to prevent the browsers deafult shortkeys.

I did this by using jquerys event.preventDeafult and this did the trick for all browsers BUT IE10. The problem that i have is when i press ctrl + p i get the print action in IE10

These are the attempts that I have tried so far:

```
if (e.ctrlKey && $(".ui-dialog").length <=0) {

    if (e.ctrlKey && noDeafultButtons) {
        //e.preventDefault();
        //(e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
        //e.stopPropagation();
        //////e.returnValue = false
        ////if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.preventDefault();
        } else {
            e.returnValue = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Any1 that has any ideas on how i can solve this?
If im unclear just ask!

Thanks!

EDIT:

I would like to clarify that the code above is inside of a keydown event. 
I have successfully implemented the shortkeys i wish to have and they all work exept ctrl + p in IE10

Comment: I think IE still responds to `return false;` have you tried?

Comment: I tried return false and it did not work.To clarify:
I added return false fruther down the script block since this is only a small part of the script that prevents the browsers deafult behavior which in turn enabels me to se my shortkeys. However retunr did not work and i would also like to point out that i am not getting any errors

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts is this usefull?

Comment: Is is ussfull in the sense that one might get a greater understanding on how to implement what I have already done but for my specific problem it is not that usefull. Thanks anyways

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while but i found the soloution.

At the end of my code I hade 2 set the event.keycode to 0 so that the browser did not have any key to attach to. In my opinion this is a dirty soloution and there is always a risk that microsoft realizes this and prevents it but for now it works.

Soloution:

```
 event.keyCode = 0;
 return false;
```

Comment: I forgott 2 mention that this can have an undesierd effect if you are not careful. This resets all keys that were pressed so if you want to reload the page using ctrl+F5 then it wont work since the browser doesnt have any keys to attach this to. Put some conditional logic arround this so that it does what you expect it to and voila!