# is there a way to prevent HTML's accesskey="" from being activated?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, accessibility, wai-aria

I tried `preventDefault()` but I haven't had success. Is there something that I'm missing?

I would try to disable it globally, if possible (like registering the events on `window`)

Comment: key combination is platform dependent, but i'm talking of html accesskeys

Comment: Why not just remove the attributes?

Comment: i think that would affect accessibility... is that the only option?

Comment: Ehh...? Would it just have the same affect as `preventDefault()` (assuming `preventDefault()` would have been working)? Attributes can be removed/returned with JS, you don't have to remove them from the file, if that's your point.

Comment: Your solution will indeed affect the accessibility. Because a screen reader would say, for example, "Save button alt+S", but when the user presses alt+S, nothing would happen because of your `preventDefault()` or whatever. So just remove the `accesskey` attribute.

Comment: This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 11):

There doesn't seem to be a way to stop the event from triggering. The only alternative seems to be to remove the accesskey attributes temporarily while you don't want them to work. That's what [jQuery UI has to do for modal dialogs](https://forum.jquery.com/topic/jquery-ui-modal-dialog-not-blocking-accesskey-of-buttons-on-parent-window).

Here's the code from that thread:

```
$("#boxA-dialog").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    height: 400,
    width: 300,
    open: function(event, ui) {
        ak = $('[accesskey]').each(function() {
            $(this).data('ak', $(this).attr('accesskey')).removeAttr('accesskey')
        })
    },
    close: function(event, ui) {
        ak.each(function() {
            $(this).attr('accesskey', $(this).data('ak'))
        })
    }
});
```

As you can see it's saving the accesskey attributes to jQuery data before removing them:

```
$(this).data('ak', $(this).attr('accesskey')).removeAttr('accesskey')
```

and then restoring them from the data:

```
$(this).attr('accesskey', $(this).data('ak'))
```

I'd be interested in a solution that actually prevents the event rather than using this workaround.

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand your problem, you could try this.

```
$('[accesskey*=]').focus(function(e) { 
    // disable accesskey functionality 
});
$('[accesskey*=]').blur(function(e) { 
    // reenable accesskey functionality 
});
```

Comment: That would be too late as whatever element was in focus would have lost focus by this point.

Answer (score 0):

Using the previous answer, you can use this trick to "remove" all "accesskey" options from the page.

```
$('[accesskey*=]').attr('accesskey','');
```

Simply set all accesskey on the page for nothing.

Comment: You might need to restore the attributes though.

Comment: But that's not what the question was about. so no need to over complicate it, no ?

Comment: If they're just going to be removed they shouldn't be there in the first place. I'm assuming from Wes's use of the word "prevent" that he only wants them blocked under certain conditions and that when those conditions aren't met they should work as normal.

Comment: then he will just have to put the conditions around the jQuery function. not hard to implement, in any case, wes is not choosing/answering to the thread, so let's just leave it there. unless you found the "workaround" solution. would be interested!

Comment: I don't think I've explained myself very well. When I said "under certain conditions" I mean that at different points in time the accesskeys should and shouldn't work. So at one point in time you might want the accesskey removed, and then later, you might want it restored. So putting a condition around the jQuery won't work; it does not provide a way to restore the attribute later.