# Javascript event.stopPropagation() doesn't work with `accesskey` attribute

Tags: javascript, html, browser

A simple html page contains only two controls, one textbox and one button. After page load if user clicks inside textbox and press “alt” + p (button accesskey) the message should be displayed as “I'm from key down!!!” but if the user clicks anywhere other than inside textbox, the message should be displayed as “I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!”. Complete code is shown below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyDown() {
        if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
            event.returnValue = false;
            event.cancelBubble = true;
            event.keyCode = 0;
            alert("I'm from key down!!!");
        }
    }

    function clickMe() {
        alert("I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!");
    }
 </script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="text" onkeydown ="keyDown();" />
    <input type="button" value="Click me" accesskey="p" onclick="clickMe();" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It works fine in IE10 and below. But it doesn’t work in IE11 and Chrome, instead it shows two alert messages one after another like “I'm from key down!!!” and “I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!” which is not desirable. So the `keyDown()` event handler is changed to support IE10+ and Chrome like

```
function keyDown() {
     if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
        event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : (event.returnValue = false);
        event.stopPropagation ? event.stopPropagation() : (event.cancelBubble = true);
        event.keyCode = 0;
        alert("I'm from key down!!!");
     }
}
```

But in this scenario event.stopPropagation() doesn’t work, any idea why?

Comment: How do you know that `stopPropagation` doesn't work?

Comment: Because both alert messages are getting fired.

Comment: *"Because both alert messages are getting fired."* There is only a single event handler that is listening to `keydown` events. Stopping the propagation means that another `keydown` event handler that is attached to an **ancestor** of the `<input>` element is not fired. Maybe instead of telling us what "doesn't work", explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: Focusing outside the textbox shouldn't trigger clickMe() since it's only bound to the button's click event.

Comment: @YoannM: `event` is global in IE and Chrome.

Comment: Can you please show me some sample - it works fine in IE10.

Comment: @FelixKling : oups... I'll remove my misleading comment then.

Comment: Can't repro: http://jsfiddle.net/8vk8x8gt/. I only see a single `alert` in Chrome, even with the old code. Either way, `keydown` and `click` are two distinctive events, handled completely independently.

Comment: Click in textbox (IE10) - it shows "I'm from key down!!!" but in Chrome it shows "I'm from key down!!!", also shows "I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!" but I'm expecting only one message i.e., "I'm from key down!!!".

Comment: @FelixKling In the fiddle when I hold down alt + P I see the first alert come up, then immediately the focus goes to the button. Once I click OK on the alert to dismiss it I get the second alert. Oddly enough, if I change the code to respond to only the alt key or the p key that same behavior doesn't occur.

Comment: @j08691: No idea. I only see a single alert :P

Comment: Can't you just check whether the input has focus or not inside your `clickMe()` ?

Comment: Some workaround may be possible but that needs code changes in several places as same kind of scenarios spread across multiple pages. Trying to avoid (if possible).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's just a workaround, can't be a proper solution - the `accesskey` attribute is the issue, so this attribute to be removed temporarily and add it once again as @gfullam has explained. This can be done effectively by using jquery but it's unknown why stopPropagation() doesn't work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function keyDown(evt) {
        var e = evt || window.event;
        if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
           //event.returnValue = false;
           //event.cancelBubble = true;
           //event.keyCode = 0;
            var allAccessKeys = $('[accesskey]').each(function () {
                $(this).data('allAccessKeys', $(this).attr 
                ('accesskey')).removeAttr('accesskey');
            });

            alert("I'm from key down!!!");

            setTimeout(function () {
                allAccessKeys.each(function () {
                    $(this).attr('accesskey', $(this).data 
                    ('allAccessKeys'));
                });
            }, 0);
        }
    }

    function clickMe() {
        alert("I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!");
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div>
    <input type="text" onkeydown="keyDown(event);" />
    <input type="button" value="Click me" accesskey="p" onclick="clickMe();" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I suggested a jQuery solution in my original answer (see it struck through in my updated answer). I elaborated in plain JS because you didn't respond or vote on my original answer. You also didn't use jQuery in your original post. If you're going to be using jQuery, it would also be better to remove the event handler attributes from your HTML and bind them dynamically in the script.

Answer (score 2):

## The `accesskey` event always gets triggered

### *(unless you temporarily disable it)*

Most browsers will always trigger events bound to `accesskey` attributes, even if other bound event handlers use common tactics such as `return false`, `stopPropagation`, `stopImmediatePropagation`, `preventDefault`, `cancelBubble`, etc., which are otherwise effective at stopping event bubbling and default behavior under normal circumstances.

But in your case, you have a handler checking for the same key combination as you have bound via `accesskey` to another element. So every time that key combo is input while the text field has focus, both handlers get fired: first in the `keyDown` handler, then regardless of any attempt to stop that event from bubbling, the `clickMe` handler is triggered because it is activated by the `accesskey`.

One solution is to remove `accesskey` attributes temporarily when you don't want to listen to them (such as when your text input has focus) and then restore them when you don't want to ignore them anymore (such as when your text input loses focus).

<s>See [this answer for a jQuery powered solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22842358/2502532) that you can use as a springboard to create a plain JS solution to suit your needs.</s>

**Example:**

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
  
  /* Function to cache accesskey attributes */
  function cacheAccessKeys() {
    
    /* Get all elements with accesskeys
    // This could be modified to select a smaller subset of elements */
    var akEls = document.querySelectorAll('[accesskey]');
    
    /* Iterate over each element in the set of matched elements */
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(akEls, function (el, i) {
      
      /* Set the value of data-accesskey to the value of accesskey */
      el.setAttribute('data-accesskey', el.getAttribute('accesskey'));
      
      /* Remove the accesskey attribute
      // to temporarily disable accesskey binding */
      el.removeAttribute('accesskey');
    });
  }

  /* Function to restore accesskey attributes */
  function restoreAccessKeys() {
    
    /* Get all elements with accesskeys
    // This could be modified to select a smaller subset of elements */
    var akEls = document.querySelectorAll('[data-accesskey]');
    
    /* Iterate over each element in the set of matched elements */
    Array.prototype.forEach.call(akEls, function (el, i) {
      
      /* Set the value of accesskey to the value of data-accesskey
      // to restore accesskey binding */
      el.setAttribute('accesskey', el.getAttribute('data-accesskey'));
      
      /* Clean-up (perhaps unnecessary) 
      // In case the accesskey attributes are set dynamically elsewhere,
      // this prevents mismatched caching. */
      el.removeAttribute('data-accesskey');
    });
  }

  function keyDown(e) {
    if (e.altKey && e.keyCode === 80) {
      console.log("I'm from key down!!!");
    }
  }

  function clickMe() {
    console.log("I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!");
  }
</script>

<div>
  
  
  <!-- On focus: Cache/remove accesskey attributes -->
  <!-- On keydown: Now the key combo in here won't trigger other handlers. -->
  <!-- On blur: Restore accesskey attributes -->
  <input type="text"
         onfocus="cacheAccessKeys();"
         onkeydown="keyDown(event);"
         onblur="restoreAccessKeys();"
         />
         
  <!-- On click: Activated by Alt + p access key combo
  //-- only when text field does NOT have focus. -->
  <input type="button"
         accesskey="p"
         value="Click me"
         onclick="clickMe();"
         />
</div>
```

Comment: It works in Chrome but not in IE10. I agree with this approach. Thank you!.

Answer (score 1):

The `accesskey` attribute seems to be the issue. Chrome and IE use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>accesskey</kbd> to activate the key press. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Global_attributes/accesskey. Remove that and the issue goes away.

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/2efgbde1/)**

Comment: Thank you! But users always prefer "alt" + p instead of mouse click on "Click Me" button (IE10 & below) and now we are supporting IE11 and Chrome, so we can't remove "alt" + p.

Comment: Well as long as you include that you're going to have that issue.

Comment: Agreed, I think you're going to have to check against `document.activeElement`

Answer (score 1):

Here is another workaround just disable only the enabled accesskey element and     re enable it after that.

```
    function keyDown() {
        if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
          var accecskeyObj = $("input[accesskey=" + event.key + "][disabled != disabled]");
         accecskeyObj.prop('disabled',true);
         alert("I'm from key down!!!");
         accecskeyObj.prop('disabled',false);
        }
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2efgbde1/1/

Answer (score 0):

You didn't pass the event object.

```
function keyDown(e) {

     var e = event || window.event;
     if (e.altKey && e.keyCode == 80) {
        e.preventDefault ? e.preventDefault() : (e.returnValue = false);
        e.stopPropagation ? e.stopPropagation() : (e.cancelBubble = true);
        e.keyCode = 0;
     }
}
```

But since, it's defined global it shouldn't be the problem. I checked and on adding any kind of accesskey, chrome bypassing two alert boxes back to back.

To get away with the problem, I don't think you have any other option rather than removing the access key. On removing it, it's displaying the same result on both chrome and IE.

```
<input type="text" onkeydown="keyDown();" />
<input type="button" value="Click me" onclick="clickMe();" />

function keyDown() {
    if (event.altKey && event.keyCode == 80) {
        event.returnValue = false;
        event.cancelBubble = true;
        event.keyCode = 0;
        alert("I'm from key down!!!");
    }
}

function clickMe() {
    alert("I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!");
}
```

Comment: While it's good practice to pass the event object, it wouldn't make a difference here since `event` is global in IE and Chrome. Whatever the OP's problem is, this is not a solution to it.

Comment: @FelixKling Oh. I thought that might led to the problem because it was quite clear and visible.

Comment: @SudiptaMaiti Your alert is showing twice when onfocus on the textfield. That's pretty interesting. What is the result that you are getting?

Comment: Click in textbox (IE10) and press "alt" + P - it shows "I'm from key down!!!" but in Chrome it shows "I'm from key down!!!", also shows "I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!" but I'm expecting only one message i.e., "I'm from key down!!!". But if user clicks anywhere else other than textbox and press "alt" + P - it should be "I should be called only when the focus is outside the textbox!!!".

Comment: To clarify, even if it isn't the cause of the OP's problem, you were right the standard practice is receiving the event as a parameter. The global `event` variable isn't standard and is not supported on Firefox.

Comment: @Oriol That's what I thought about earlier. But since, the problem with his question lies within IE and Chrome, so ignored it. But suitable practice is to pass it as a parameter overall.