# How can I prevent Ctrl-- and Ctrl-+?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, preventdefault

Google Chrome has the key binding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> for decreasing font size and and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>+</kbd> for increasing font size. I want to prevent them. I figured out that they are bound to `<body>`, and I did:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keyup',
  function(obj, e){e.preventDefault();}, false);
```

but it seems that in/decreasing font size is triggered before the event is sent to these handlers, and by the time `preventDefault()` is run, they are already done, and my attempt fails. How can I prevent **these default bindings**?

**To (potential) downvoters**: Read my question above carefully. I never wrote that I want to prevent zooming entirely. I want to unbind these functions from the particular key combinations that I mention. And if you think freeing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> should not be done, then why does the [Ace editor](http://ace.c9.io/#nav=about) ships emacs keybinding with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>-</kbd> bound to undo? Are you claiming that the developers of Ace editor (including Mozilla Firefox developers, among others) are doing something useless? Are you saying that you are superior than them? And even if your suggestion is not to do it, why downvote instead of writing that as an answer?

Comment: Why prevent it? It's an important accessibility feature.

Comment: The size can be modified using many other method than keyboard shortcuts. Just blocking those will not prevent font size changes.

Comment: You would have to use keydown. however, you're fighting a losing battle. If someone is zooming in your site, it's because they need to do that to be able to read it. you're impacting accessibility

Comment: @p.s.w.g I rarely use it. I am embedding a javascript-based text editor with emacs key binding, and Ctrl-- conflicts with the emacs undo.

Comment: to prevent it... isn't that what your question is about? (i updated my comment btw, i hit enter too soon)

Comment: It would probably be important to point out in the question that you're trying to rebind that key combination to a different behavior. As it stands now it sounds like you just want to disable the browser's zoom feature.

Comment: @KevinB So what? How is the availability of zooming relevant to my question?

Comment: You are specifically impacting the user's ability to zoom. That makes it very relevant to your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: *"then why does the Ace editor ships emacs keybinding with Ctrl-- bound to undo?"* they are doing that within the editor, not for the entire document. the same goes for the editor you used to create your question.

Comment: I did not dv because this is a valid question, regardless of whether or not i agree with the practice. It is however a duplicate.

Comment: @KevinB Thanks for the clarification. If I can disable that binding only within the embedded editor, then that is fine (although I don't have strong motivation to do so), but since it is bound to the body, doesn't it have to be unbound from the body? Is it possible to selectively unbind if for certain elements?

Comment: *"doesn't it have to be unbound from the body?"* no, you just wouldn't bind to the body in the first place. you would instead bind to a container of the editor. *"Is it possible to selectively unbind if for certain elements?"* No, but you could selectively decide to prevent the default based on what the `event.target` is, allowing it for everything other than the editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one uses jQuery and checks to see if: the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key is pressed and the <kbd>+</kbd>/<kbd>-</kbd> buttons are pressed.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
    if(e.ctrlKey
       && (e.which == 107 || e.which == 109 || e.which == 187 || e.which == 189))
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: This is better than my original idea as it selectively unbinds particular functions.

Answer (score 2):

If you bind to the `keydown` event and you use `e` as the first argument, this code will work:

```
document.body.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}, false);
```

[**Demonstration**](http://jsfiddle.net/vXNWq/embedded/result/)

Note that this method does nothing to disable the browser's zoom feature, it just prevents the default behavior of all keyboard shortcuts. For example, you can still zoom with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>mouse wheel</kbd>.

Comment: Because of the negative reaction of the community, it took me a while to realize that there were answers given.