# Actionscript 3.0: How do I override browser keyboard shortcuts?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, browser, actionscript, keyboard

I have a .swf that requires Ctrl+N and Ctrl+T as keyboard shortcuts, however when in a browser this opens a new window or a new tab (respectively).

My question is, how do I (or even *can* I) override this using only Actionscript 3.0?

Best regards!

Answer (score 0):

I guess, you cant do this via AS3. But, if your flash runs in IFrame, you can try do this via JS.

here is solution for JS: [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)