# Block source view from opening when ctrl+u is being pressed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a way to block the source view from opening when someone presses ctrl+u using javascript/jquery. The reason for this is that I'm making some sort of simple text-editor, and I made it so that ctrl+u inserts tags for underline. I got that working, except it also opens the sourcecode view, which I don't want.

#### Note:

> I'm not trying to block users from viewing my source code all
> together. I've seen questions such as this one being shot down for
> reasons such as "people will be able to view your code anyway and
> there's nothing that can be done about it, it's pointless". That is
> not what I'm trying to accomplish here.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)

Comment: Yes, e.preventDefault(); is exactly what I was looking for. This question can be marked as answered!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To override a browser's native keyboard shortcut, use the `Event.preventDefault()` method, which will tell the browser not to handle the keyboard event as it usually would.

```
$(document).keydown(function (e) {
    if (e.keyCode === 85 && e.ctrlKey) {
        e.preventDefault();
        // ... your handling here ...
    }
});
```