# Preventing default browser keypress to implement key combination in javaScript using key name not keycode

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am creating a web application where I need to add some certain numbers of key press functionalities. I am fetching those keys from a sql query. As I am taking the keys from DB so I can not use keycode (key "F" code is "70"). I have tried with the following code but it is not working.Can someone explain?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
        if (e.key = "F" && e.altKey) {
            alert('done');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    })
        });
    </script>
```

Comment: Please, read this article: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 0):

KeyCode for F key is **70**

```
document.getElementById('foo').onkeydown = function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
//alert(e.keyCode);
    switch( e.keyCode || e.which) {
        case 70: // F key
        case 65: // A key
            if( e.altKey) {
            return false;
            }
    }
}
```

Check clicking `ALT + F` on first `input` and second `input` and see the difference

**[FIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vaibviad/egJyT/61/)**

Note:Tested on chrome

Comment: I can not use key code as because I am fetching the keys from a sql DB. I can not change the DB. So instead of key code I have to use specific key letters only.

Comment: @Code, it is really expensive to be storing and retrieving something like keycodes in the DB. They could easily be stored in a JS Object.