# Is it possible to prevent a user from saving a webpage with CTRL + S? (asking for a friend)

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to stop the `Save as website.html` from appearing when you press CTRL + S in either HTML, Javascript, or CSS? ***This is so that when you press CTRL + S, you can add a shortcut to save your progress, and not the website***

Comment: No, but even if it were, anything with a URL can be downloaded without a browser.

Comment: Is this about preventing Ctrl+S specifically or "stealing" of source code in general?

Comment: Don't be so user hostile. Let browser features work.

Comment: Regardless of what you do to prevent this, it will still be able to saved. Same goes for blocking copy&paste - it's just bad UX.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Overriding Browser's Keyboard Shortcuts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can prevent this by using `Event.preventDefault()`

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(event) {
  if (event.ctrlKey && event.key === 's') {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert('Save Event!');
  }
});

More Details:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(document).on("keydown", function(e) { 
    if ( e.ctrlKey && ( e.which === 83 ) ) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    });
```