# Prevent print dialog from showing when pressing Ctrl + P

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, event-handling, html2canvas

I have an angular app and I don't want the printDialog to open when pressing "Ctrl + P".
I've added the following code

```js
 window.onbeforeprint = (event) => {
      event.stopPropagation();
      console.log('Before print');
    };
```

I can see my log in the console but the window is displayed.
What I would like to do is to use html2canvas and jsPDF to screen my app instead of using window print.

How can I achieve that ?

Comment: It's not a great idea to override the default browser behavior unless you really have a great reason. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be able to use this:

```
  @HostListener('window:keydown.control.p', ['$event'])
  preventPrint(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Print prevention will only occur when the component in question is on screen. If you would like for your whole app to prevent printing then you can put this on your root app component.

Comment: works like a charm! how can I do the same for the right click + print ? I tried adding an event listener  to : var mediaQueryList = window.matchMedia('print') but this does not work.

Comment: Not sure, you might want to post a separate question for that