# How to capture `Ctrl+1` hotkey on Chrome browser keydown event?

Tags: html, google-chrome, dom-events, keydown, hotkeys

I'm now developing a website for mindmap manipulation, and now want to make some hotkeys to make operations better.

In XMind, `Ctrl+1` stands for adding a label with number 1, but I found the keydown event cannot capture the event. Instead, `Ctrl+1` leads to activating the first Chrome tab, even though I call the `e.preventDefault()`.

So the priority of the chrome browser is the most significant so cannot be intercepted. If I want to make the `Ctrl+1` hotkey act as expect, is there any solution?

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.ctrlKey && e.code === 'Digit1') {
        // ...
        e.preventDefault()
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
document.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode)
    if (e.ctrlKey && [49, 50, 51].includes(e.keyCode)) {
        e.preventDefault()
        console.log('hahahah')
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680919/overriding-browsers-keyboard-shortcuts) seems to have a discussion that might answer your question.

Easiest one to try among the answers there is to use `e.preventDefault(); e.stopPropagation()`. Hope that thread answers your question.

Comment: Thank you for the great clue for my question.